# Hibernate 6 QuarkusH2Dialect registerFunction removed

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

I’m using Quarkus and Hibernate. There is a custom class which extends QuarkusH2Dialect. But after migration to Hibernate 6 it doesn’t work anymore. It's been removed. Could you please provide some pieces of advice, how to fix it?

```
import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.dialect.QuarkusH2Dialect
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.Mapping
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor
import org.hibernate.type.StringType
import org.hibernate.type.Type

class MyDialect : QuarkusH2Dialect() {

    init {
        registerFunction(
            "calculate_hash",
            object : SQLFunction {
                override fun hasArguments() = true
                override fun hasParenthesesIfNoArguments() = false
                override fun getReturnType(firstArgumentType: Type?, mapping: Mapping?) = StringType.INSTANCE
                override fun render(firstArgumentType: Type?, arguments: List<Any?>?, factory: SessionFactoryImplementor?) =
                    "hash('calculate_hash', ${arguments?.first()})"
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just extend `org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`.

Or, better, register your function through a custom `MetadataBuilderContributor`:

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.metadata-builder-contributor=com.acme.MyMetadataBuilderConstributor
```

```java
public class CustomMetadataBuilderContributor implements  org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataBuilderContributor,
        FunctionContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applyFunctions(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void contributeFunctions(FunctionContributions functionContributions) {
        TypeConfiguration typeConfiguration = functionContributions.getTypeConfiguration();
        functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().register(
                "myFunction",
                new MyFunction(...));
    }

    private static final class MyFunction implements SQLFunction {
        ...
    }
}
```

Related: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/32936